# MySQL query with many joins

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

I have query with many joins and I'm searching for optimization for it.
It's about computers:
For examples I have:
Lenovo 8gbRAM 1TB core i5 ips etc. (all these after brand name are attributes)
I have configuration where, I want to change attribute 8gbRAM to 16gbRAM and I have to search for other item with all these attributes and 16gbRAM

Two tables:

```
**st_item**
- id
- name
...

**st_item_specification_attribute**
- id
- st_item_id
- attribute_id
- attribute_value_id
...
```

My problem is that my item has 15 attributes. When I tested with lower number of attributes I use this structure of query and it works, but now system has 85k items and over 1kk item attributes
This is the query:

```
SELECT `st_item`.id FROM `st_item` 
LEFT JOIN `st_item_specification_attribute` `sisa_36590` ON st_item.id = sisa_36590.item_id AND sisa_36590.attribute_id = 365 
LEFT JOIN `st_item_specification_attribute` `sisa_367910` ON st_item.id = sisa_367910.item_id AND sisa_367910.attribute_id = 367 
LEFT JOIN `st_item_specification_attribute` `sisa_374641` ON st_item.id = sisa_374641.item_id AND sisa_374641.attribute_id = 374 
LEFT JOIN `st_item_specification_attribute` `sisa_378366` ON st_item.id = sisa_378366.item_id AND sisa_378366.attribute_id = 378 
LEFT JOIN `st_item_specification_attribute` `sisa_382500` ON st_item.id = sisa_382500.item_id AND sisa_382500.attribute_id = 382 
LEFT JOIN `st_item_specification_attribute` `sisa_372134` ON st_item.id = sisa_372134.item_id AND sisa_372134.attribute_id = 372 
LEFT JOIN `st_item_specification_attribute` `sisa_41268` ON st_item.id = sisa_41268.item_id AND sisa_41268.attribute_id = 412 
LEFT JOIN `st_item_specification_attribute` `sisa_413368` ON st_item.id = sisa_413368.item_id AND sisa_413368.attribute_id = 413 
LEFT JOIN `st_item_specification_attribute` `sisa_414929` ON st_item.id = sisa_414929.item_id AND sisa_414929.attribute_id = 414 
LEFT JOIN `st_item_specification_attribute` `sisa_418496` ON st_item.id = sisa_418496.item_id AND sisa_418496.attribute_id = 418 
LEFT JOIN `st_item_specification_attribute` `sisa_385748` ON st_item.id = sisa_385748.item_id AND sisa_385748.attribute_id = 385 
LEFT JOIN `st_item_specification_attribute` `sisa_36625` ON st_item.id = sisa_36625.item_id AND sisa_36625.attribute_id = 366 
LEFT JOIN `st_item_specification_attribute` `sisa_366355` ON st_item.id = sisa_366355.item_id AND sisa_366355.attribute_id = 366 
LEFT JOIN `st_item_specification_attribute` `sisa_366816` ON st_item.id = sisa_366816.item_id AND sisa_366816.attribute_id = 366 
LEFT JOIN `st_item_specification_attribute` `sisa_366370` ON st_item.id = sisa_366370.item_id AND sisa_366370.attribute_id = 366 
WHERE (`parent_id`=1032) AND 
(sisa_36590.attribute_value_id = 2230) AND 
(sisa_367910.attribute_value_id = 2451) AND 
(sisa_374641.attribute_value_id = 3793) AND 
(sisa_378366.attribute_value_id = 2955) AND 
(sisa_382500.attribute_value_id = 3879) AND 
(sisa_372134.attribute_value_id = 2780) AND 
(sisa_41268.attribute_value_id = 3363) AND 
(sisa_413368.attribute_value_id = 3373) AND 
(sisa_414929.attribute_value_id = 3378) AND 
(sisa_418496.attribute_value_id = 3844) AND 
(sisa_385748.attribute_value_id = 3036) AND 
(sisa_36625.attribute_value_id = 2315) AND 
(sisa_366355.attribute_value_id = 2408) AND 
(sisa_366816.attribute_value_id = 2412) AND 
(sisa_366370.attribute_value_id = 2420)
```

Query must compare specific pair `attribute_id => attribute_value_id`, that's the reason my "ON clause" to be with `item_id` and `attribute_id` and specific `alias`

Comment: All those left joins are turned into inner joins because of that where clause. I can't say if that's what you intend

Comment: You must move those conditions from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause.

Comment: EAV schema design == Yuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select i.id
from st_item i join
     st_item_specification_attribute sisa
     ON sisa.item_id = i.item_id
where i.parent_id = 1032 and
      (sisa.attribute_id, attribute_value_id) in ( (365, 2230), (367, 2451), . . .)
group by i.id
having count(*) = 15;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move your `WHERE` conditions into `ON` conditions
and change `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT `st_item`.id FROM `st_item` 
JOIN `st_item_specification_attribute` `sisa_36590` 
ON st_item.id = sisa_36590.item_id AND sisa_36590.attribute_id = 365
  AND sisa_36590.attribute_value_id = 2230 
JOIN `st_item_specification_attribute` `sisa_367910`
ON st_item.id = sisa_367910.item_id AND sisa_367910.attribute_id = 367 
 AND sisa_367910.attribute_value_id = 2451 
...
WHERE `parent_id`=1032
```

### 2nd approach

```
SELECT `st_item`.id FROM `st_item` 
JOIN `st_item_specification_attribute` `sisa` 
ON st_item.id = sisa.item_id AND 
  (
   (sisa.attribute_id = 365 AND sisa.attribute_value_id = 2230)
   OR
   (sisa.attribute_id = 367 AND sisa.attribute_value_id = 2451) 
    ...
  )
WHERE `parent_id`=1032
GROUP BY `st_item`.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 15
```

Comment: And how do you suggest to change the structure?

Comment: I have one table "st_item_specification_attribute" where are stored all item attributes, sisa is the alias. But there is feature that one attribute_id have specifically value_id

Answer (score 0):

I cannot predict the performance, but I think you could make on subselect out of all that joins

(I presume atribute_id and Attribute_value_id pairs are unique per item_id)

```
SELECT `st_item`.id FROM `st_item` 
WHERE (`parent_id`=1032) AND 
  15 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM st_item_specification_attribute attr
         WHERE `st_item`.id = attr.item_id 
           AND (  attribute_id = 365 AND attribute_value_id = 2230 OR
                  ...
               )
```

Comment: But in the end its quite the same as @Alex second approach(depends on the optimizer)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a UNION ALL approach for this. It's easy to change, and fairly simple to read. Performance should be pretty good too:

```
--A CTE so you only have to change parent_id in one place
--I believe not all mysql versions support this, though
--You could of course just select the parent_id in de UNION ALL and 
--   use a single WHERE in the outer query. 
WITH st_item_id AS
(
    SELECT  id
    ,       attribute_id
    ,       attribute_value_id
    FROM    st_item
    WHERE   parent_id = 1032
)

SELECT  UA.id
FROM    (
            SELECT  st_item.id 
            FROM    st_item_id 
            INNER JOIN st_item_specification_attribute sisa_36590 
                    ON st_item_id.id = sisa_36590.item_id 
                    AND sisa_36590.attribute_id = 365 
                    AND sisa_36590.attribute_value_id = 2230

            UNION ALL 

            SELECT  st_item.id 
            FROM    st_item_id 
            INNER JOIN st_item_specification_attribute sisa_367910 
                    ON st_item_id.id = sisa_367910.item_id 
                    AND sisa_367910.attribute_id = 367 
                    AND sisa_367910.attribute_value_id = 2451
        ) UA
```